# How to resize the magento 2 product images

Tags: magento2

I need to resize the magento2 product images to  150px *  150 how can we achieve this 
[image]

Comment: could you please share file name and path ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change image size form `view.xml`.

You can find `view.xml` at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/etc/view.xml

Now Open your phtml and search `$image` variable.This variable holds Id of image.
Search this Id in `view.xml` and change accordingly.

**Example:** If your phtml for new product is:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml

You can find Id of image i.e `new_products_content_widget_grid`.
search this Id in `view.xml` and change

**Note:** If `view.xml` is not available in your theme, you can copy form theme's parent theme.

Comment: please let me know if have any issue..